# Winsock Connection C++ not connecting to either IPv4 or External Ip Address

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

So I have been developing something for multi-computer use (I'm working on a botnet in order to prove for a school project that computers can be easily hacked as a project for GITA) and I can't seem to make a connection with the server and client. The client can connect via 127.0.0.1, however, when attempted to connect via IPv4 or the external ip (can be found www.whatsmyip.org) it doesn't seem to work. So I have tried everything, even disabling my firewall but nothing.

I'm wondering if I happened to make a mistake in my code?

Client:

```
#include "client.h"

Client* Client::clientptr;

int Client::Initalize(const char* add)
{
    char ownPth[MAX_PATH];

    // When NULL is passed to GetModuleHandle, the handle of the exe itself is returned
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (hModule != NULL)
    {
        // Use GetModuleFileName() with module handle to get the path
        GetModuleFileName(hModule, ownPth, (sizeof(ownPth)));
        std::cout << ownPth << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Module handle is NULL" << std::endl;
    }

    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);

    if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: WINSOCK INVALID!" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    std::cout << "Setting SOCKADDR_IN addr..." << std::endl;
    addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(add);
    addr.sin_port = htons(4403);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Attempting connection..." << std::endl;
        if (connect(connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, addrlen) > 0 || connect == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Connection established!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        std::cout << "Error: Failed to connect! Retrying... " << std::endl;

        Sleep(1000);

    }

    clientptr = this;

    return 0;
}

int Client::Run()
{
    std::cout << std::endl << "Running..." << std::endl;

    while (true)
    {

        Sleep(10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Server:

```
#include "server.h"

Server* Server::serverptr; //Serverptr is necessary so the static ClientHandler method can access the server instance/functions.

int Server::Initalize()
{
    std::cout << "Setting crash handler..." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Looking at winsock dll version..." << std::endl;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    std::cout << "Creating listening socket..." << std::endl;

    addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    addr.sin_port = htons(4403);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    std::cout << "The socket data addr "
        << "{"
        << "addr.sin_addr.s_addr = " << addr.sin_addr.s_addr
        << ", addr.sin_port = " << addr.sin_port
        << ", addr.sin_family = " << addr.sin_family
        << "}" << std::endl;

    sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL); //Create socket to listen for new connections
    if (bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) //Bind the address to the socket, if we fail to bind the address..
    {
        std::string ErrorMsg = "Failed to bind the address to our listening socket. Winsock Error:" + std::to_string(WSAGetLastError());
        MessageBoxA(NULL, ErrorMsg.c_str(), "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) //Places sListen socket in a state in which it is listening for an incoming connection. Note:SOMAXCONN = Socket Oustanding Max connections, if we fail to listen on listening socket...
    {
        std::string ErrorMsg = "Failed to listen on listening socket. Winsock Error:" + std::to_string(WSAGetLastError());
        MessageBoxA(NULL, ErrorMsg.c_str(), "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(1);
    }

    std::cout << "Finalizing..." << std::endl;
    output = false;
    currClient = 0;

    std::cout << "Setting serverptr..." << std::endl;

    serverptr = this;

    std::cout << "Creating Threads..." << std::endl;

    serverptr->Listening = false;

    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Listen, NULL, NULL, NULL); //Create thread that will manage all outgoing packets

    while (serverptr->Listening == false);

    std::cout << "Done Initalizing!" << std::endl << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int Server::Run()
{
    std::cout << "Running server...";

    serverptr->Listening = true;

    while (true)
    {
        std::string userinput;
        int inputInt;
        HANDLE hConsoe = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        while (true)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << "] ";
            std::getline(std::cin, userinput);
            serverptr->HandleInput(userinput);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void Server::Listen()
{
    if (serverptr->output)
        std::cout << "Listener socket running..." << std::endl;

    serverptr->Listening = true;

    while (true)
    {
        if (serverptr->Listening == true)
        {

            SOCKET newConnection    //the connection for the socket
                = accept(serverptr->sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&serverptr->addr, &serverptr->addrlen); //Accept a new connection

            if (newConnection == 0)
            {
                if (serverptr->output)
                    std::cout << "FAILED TO ACCEPT THE CLIENTS CONNECTION!" << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {

                if (serverptr->output)
                {
                    std::cout << "A connection has been made [" << inet_ntoa(serverptr->addr.sin_addr) << "]!" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "Creating Client(" << newConnection << ")..." << std::endl;
                }

                Client newClient(newConnection, serverptr->addr);
                int connectionId = serverptr->clients.size();

                serverptr->clients.push_back(newClient);

                CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)RecvClient, NULL, NULL, NULL); //Create thread that will manage all incomming packets

                int index = serverptr->clients.size() - 1;

                while (!serverptr->clients[index].Listening);

                if (serverptr->output)
                    std::cout << "Client success [" << (index + 1) << "]!" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}


void Server::RecvClient()
{
    int index = serverptr->clients.size() - 1;
    char data[1600];

    if (serverptr->output)
        std::cout << "Listening for client[" << (index + 1) << "]..." << std::endl;

    serverptr->clients[index].Listening = true;

    while (true)
    {
        recv(serverptr->clients[index]._socket, data, sizeof(data), 0);
        if (serverptr->output)
            std::cout << "Data Recieved from client[" << (index + 1) << "]!" << std::endl;

        if ((int)data[0] < 0)
        {
            if (serverptr->output)
                std::cout << "Client [" << (index + 1) << "] is disconnecting with the current code {" << (int)data[0] << "}..." << std::endl;
            serverptr->DisconnectClient(index);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (serverptr->output)
        std::cout << "No longer listening for client[" << (index + 1) << "]!" << std::endl;

}

void Server::HandleInput(std::string string)
{
    std::string sHandle = string;
    std::istringstream iss(string);
    std::vector<std::string> sTokens((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss)),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

    if (sHandle == "cls")
    {
        system("cls");
        return;
    }

    if (sHandle == "list")
    {
        int index = serverptr->clients.size() - 1;

        std::cout << "Total Clients: " << serverptr->clients.size() << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < serverptr->clients.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << (char)195 << (char)196 << " Client [" << i + 1 << "] {" << serverptr->clients[i]._socket << ", " << inet_ntoa(serverptr->clients[i]._address.sin_addr) << "}" << std::endl;
        }

        return;
    }

    if (sHandle == "data")
    {
        std::cout << "Toggling data output..." << std::endl;
        serverptr->output = true;

        return;
    }

    if (sTokens[0] == "broadcast")
    {
        int change = 0;
        std::cout << "Toggling client: ";

        if (sTokens.size() > 1)
        {
            std::stringstream strings(sTokens[1]);
            strings >> change;

            if (change > serverptr->clients.size())
            {
                change = serverptr->clients.size();
            }
        }

        if (change > 0) std::cout << change << std::endl;
        else std::cout << "All" << std::endl;

        serverptr->currClient = change;

        return;
    }

    std::cout << "Error: Unknown command!" << std::endl;

    return;
}

void Server::DisconnectClient(int id)
{
    if (serverptr->output)
        std::cout << "void Server::DisconnectClient(" << id << ")..." << std::endl;
    closesocket(serverptr->clients[id]._socket);
    serverptr->clients.erase(serverptr->clients.begin() + (id));

    return;
}

Client::Client(SOCKET socket, SOCKADDR_IN address)
{
    this->_address = address;
    this->_socket = socket;
    this->Listening = false;
}
```

Comment: whatismyip will provide the address your computer has on the Internet... or a router between your PC and the Internet. In this case if client and server are inside a subnet under the router the external address will not apply and you'll probably have an address like 192.168.0.42. If the client and the server are on different sides of the router, you'll probably have to configure some port forwarding in the router to allow them to talk. If there are no routers in play, I'll be frank. You have more code here than I'm interested in wading through to figure out the problem. [mcve], please.

Comment: @user4581301 So what form of ip (pubic, ip4v, internal) can I use? Also, i have been looking at port forwarding and NAT holepunching and i have been comming up short. 


How does a normal game link to server, such as multiplayer or TeamViewer connnect?

Comment: They generally call out to a god node in the sky with the appropriate network ports open and and trust that they have written the code  correctly to keep the nasty folk out.